# How can I use the jQuery validation engine validation group?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have many buttons on my web page. I used the jQuery validation engine js. How can I control all of the input from one button. The problem is, when I click the any buttons the validation is firing.

Is there any validation group ?  I really need this now.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbyukcins" runat="server" CssClass="listboxb 
validate[required]"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbyukagirlik" runat="server" CssClass="listboxb 
validate[custom[onlyNumber]]"> </asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btteklif" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="Button1_Click"
CssClass="normal button yellow"></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation perform on OnSumbit event of Form.

Check this [link](http://encosia.com/asp-net-webforms-validation-groups-with-jquery-validation/) , u may find it useful.

Also, Its not a perfect solution but, try using different forms or using link buttons.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

You can design link buttons using css classes for example, [check this.](http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/)